# Complex vertical spacing between divs filled out with text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put more creativity in my articles by maneuvering pictures around text, and I've been using nothing but following HTML so far (and floats left or right via CSS) to "style" the article somehow;

```
<div>
<div style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">image1.jpg</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">image2.jpg</div>
'.$article['text'].'
</div>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Works fine, but.. as you can see, there is no vertical spacing between images so article can look prettier and more understandable to a reader.

I tried to find HTML&CSS to control vertical spacing between images (divs actually - in a way so text can fill out vertical spacing between images) but no dice.

Anyway, any ideas how to control that spacing? What I want to achieve is for articles to look like this:

[image]

Please, note that articles are dynamically created by PHP (not via WYSIWYG editor) so I need some "automatic" function for this. Thx!

ps: if HTML & CSS can do nothing about it, any PHP or Jquery function is also welcome. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
<div>
    <img src="image1.jpg" style="float:left; padding-right:10px;">

    FIRST PART OF TEXT

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <img src="image2.jpg" style="float:left; padding-right:10px;">

    SECOND PART OF TEXT

</div>
```

You can't really control the spacing anyway, but if the first text is long enough, it will go into the gap between the two images.

Here's a **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NVyLX/1/

Comment: Thx MightyPork, of course that does it, but I cant control HTML manually to do this, like via WYSIWYG editor for example. PHP does it all by itself (in my case). I simply need some code, plugin for Jquery or PHP function to do this alone, or something. Some "text-split" function may give a help maybe...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if you can output text from PHP, then you have complete control of the page. You can also, for example, add a css style to image, img {clear:both;}

Comment: All you need to do is this: 1. to enter (pure) text, and 2. to browse for images and via input file form are parked, resized and entered into an article by PHP alone. Creating this via WYSIWYG editor is too slow and very complex for many journalists and writters, so I programmed site to create articles (& layout) automatically.

Comment: I doubt you can achieve that without some extra markup. But you can let the "writers" use simple BBCODE-like tags: [IMG]image1.jpg[/IMG] some htext text text [CLEAR] - which ten translates to <img> and <div style="clear: both;></div>

Answer (score 0):

If you split your text into separate paragraphs, then you can float images between them.
So your code would have to be more along those lines:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">image1.jpg</div>
    <p>Article part one...</p>
    <p>Article part two...</p>
    <div style="float:left;padding-right:10px;">image2.jpg</div>
    <p>Article part three...</p>
    <p>Article part four...</p>
</div>
```

If your parts are long enough, they would fill out the gap. Otherwise the images would remain one under another.

If you really want a break, then you can use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` as in example by @MightyPork, but if you don't have enough text, you will end up with a huge break and no continuity between paragraphs.

Comment: What "huge space" you mean? If the text is long enough, there will be totally no problem, and that is what he shows in the OP.

Comment: Of course that depends on the length of paragraphs. Purely situation based.